# Raspberry Pi POST data failed Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, post, raspberry-pi

I am running a Python script on a Pi which is sending a POST request of data to my LCN main server every min, where a PHP file stores the data into a database. For most of the day it works all ok, but at night the program crashes with a Max retries exceeded. I expect this is around midnight as I always have trouble with LCN on FTP connection at midnight.

Is there something I can to to either keep retrying or to disconnect connection then reconnect and retry.

My Python script is below.

```
while 1:
    second = dt.now().second
    min = dt.now().minute
    hour = dt.now().hour

    if (hour == 00) and (min == 00) and (second < 5):
        totalTemp = []
        average = 0

    if (second == 0):
        CurrentTemp = readTemp(probeTemp)
        print ("current temp : %s" % CurrentTemp)
        totalTemp.append(CurrentTemp)
        average = round(sum(totalTemp) / len(totalTemp), 1)
        print ("average temp: %s" % average)
        myobj = {'curentTemp': CurrentTemp, 'averageTemp': average}
        x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
        time.sleep(3)
```

This is the full error I get in terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "homeTemp.py", line 37, in <module>
    x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='dansonrunners.uk', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /weatherStation/insertDB.php (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x75d7ec10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the requestpart with try-except, to prevent the python-script from crashing like this below

```
try:
    x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)

except(Exception as e): 
# can replaced with an detailed exception like requests.exceptions.*
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a go and see what happens tonight

Comment: Ok, i hope i cloud help :)

Comment: Just uploaded new code, working so far but no errors so will see if it crashes tonight, Had to remove the brackets around except part for it to work.

Comment: oh sorry, i was a little bit on java-systax in my mind "^^